# Decrement inside array in java (Array[i--])

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, decrement

I found a solution from [LeetCode](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/11919/share-my-accepted-java-solution/2)

```
public class Solution {
public void merge(int A[], int m, int B[], int n) {
    int i = m - 1, j = n - 1, k = m + n - 1;
    while(i >= 0 && j >= 0) {
        A[k--] = A[i] > B[j] ? A[i--] : B[j--];
    }
    while(j >= 0) {
        A[k--] = B[j--]; //line 8
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand what's A[k--] in java. For line 8, does it mean

```
        A[k] = B[j];
        k--;
        j--;
```

Comment: What about it don't you understand?

Comment: I said: "What about it don't you understand?"

Comment: Yes, that's effectively what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s easier with an example. Say that `k` is 5 and `j` is 2. What happens is, in order:

1. `A[k]` is located as `A[5]`
2. `k` is decremented from 5 to 4.
3. The value of `B[j]`, that is `B[2]`, is copied.
4. `j` is decremented from 2 to 1.
5. The value that was copied from `B[2]` is assigned into the location decided in 1., that is `A[5]`.

Except, the compiler is allowed to rearrange the order as long as it guarantees that the result is the same.

So yes, you are correct, the result is also the same as the result you get from:

```
    A[k] = B[j];
    k--;
    j--;
```

Answer (score 2):

`A[k--] = 2;` mean this:
"I affect the value 2 at the k index of the array and after the affectation, the k takes the value k-1"
Ex:

```
int k = 4;
int A[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
// here k=4 and A={0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
A[k--] = 12;
// Now k=3 and A={0, 0, 0, 0, 12}
```